# Coldfusion Reassign Session Variable Based on its Value

Tags: coldfusion

Is it possible to set a session variable and then to change it later if it equals a certain value?

```
<cfif session.checkout.vehicle.vehiclebody eq "TK1" or "TK2" or "TK3" or "TK4" or "TK5">
<cfparam name="#session.checkout.vehicle.vehiclebody#" default="TK">
</cfif>
```

What I am trying to do is if the session variable equals TK1,TK2,TK3,TK4, or TK5 then to reassign the session variable to equal just TK

So that then `#session.checkout.vehicle.vehiclebody# is eq to "TK"`

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Scott has given you the answer, but it's important that when you have issues, you read the docs! cfparam: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfparam & more importantly https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Using+ColdFusion+Variables (the entire section). Can I also recommend that if you're just starting out, try to avoid coding using tags, which really ought to be reserved for views, not general processing code.

Comment: He is referring to the fact that CF can be written using script syntax rather than tags and is largely the preferred choice in modern CF apps, especially in CFC's. Using this syntax helps make the transition between CF and other languages like C# and JavaScript a bit easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<cfparam name="session.checkout.vehicle.vehicleBody" default="TK" />
<cfif listFindNoCase("TK1,TK2,TK3,TK4,TK5", session.checkout.vehicle.vehicleBody)>
    <cfset session.checkout.vehicle.vehicleBody = "TK" />
</cfif>
```